# Autofac - to instantiate and to populate injected objects into a foreach constructor

Tags: autofac

i've created(instantiated) a hierarchical class structure by autofac:

```
order
   |
    --------> customerPersonDatails
   |            |
   |             ----------------->name
   |            |
   |             ------------------>surname
   |--------> customerBillingDetail
   |            |
   |             ----------------->currency
   |            |
   |            ------------------>bank
   |
   |
    --------->
```

what i want to do is "recursively" create the  the order object and populate its property

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

//register components
builder.RegisterType<order>().PropertiesAutowired().OnActivated(order_Init);  //<-- onactivated method will be used to populate  properties
builder.RegisterType<customerPersonDatails>().PropertiesAutowired();
builder.RegisterType<customerBillingDetail>().PropertiesAutowired();


public static Action<IActivatedEventArgs<order>> order_Init = (c) =>
{
        c.Instance.customerPersonDatails.name =         //<-- how to pass the current value provided from the foreach
        c.Instance.customerPersonDatails.surname = 

        c.Instance.customerBillingDetail.currency =
        c.Instance.customerBillingDetail.bank =
 };


//iteration through my orders and create recursively the object
foreach(string currentOrder in Orders)
{
    using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
          //each time "resolve" is called i get a new istance of the order object with all its properties instatiated and the OnActivated method is correctly fired
          //how can i pass into that method the currentOrder values in order to complete/populate the order structure with my values  (currentOrder.name, currentOrder.surname, ... )    
          var ord = scope.Resolve<order>();   

         //here i have to pass currentOrder's value in some way into "order_Init"(how to do it?) 


          //do others stuff
          ord.serialize();
    } 


}
```

the question is: how to pass the current value(currentOrder.name etc etc) into the function order_Init 
i've noticed the "c" parameter of the function "order_Init" has some properties like  Parameters/Context/component.... can i use one of them? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full working example, which should help you to modify your solution

```
public void Test()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<order>().PropertiesAutowired();
    //builder.RegisterType<customerPersonDatails>().PropertiesAutowired();
    //builder.RegisterType<customerBillingDetail>().PropertiesAutowired();

    var container = builder.Build();
    var Orders = new[] { "test" };
    foreach (string currentOrder in Orders)
    {
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var ordFactory = scope.Resolve<order.Factory>();  //<------changed from  "Resolve<order>" to "Resolve<order.Factory>"
            var ord = ordFactory.Invoke(currentOrder);         //<------ added in order to pass the data

        }

    } 
}

public class order
{
    //added delegate
    public delegate order Factory(string currentOrder);

    //added constructor
    public order(string currentOrder)
    {
        //use the constructor parameter to populate the class property, is it correct?     
        this.orderCode = currentOrder;
        Debug.WriteLine("I am in order constructor with currentOrder = " + currentOrder);

    }


    public string orderCode { get; set; }
```

And debug output is as expected

```
I am in order constructor with currentOrder = test
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve such possibility you should redesign your solution and invent some factory methods or Factory delegates which are supported by Autofac [Delegate Factories](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories)

Comment: no possibility to inject something at "Resolve" or "Build" time?

Comment: I am thruly think so. Autofac is not designed for such kind of things. You could defined different type of parameter resolving scenarious, but all of them have scope of component registration. If you need something from outside - use factories.